# Apache Solr 6.6.2 Performance Tuning with edismax parser

Tags: performance, solr, lucene, jetty, solrcloud

We have indexed few Million documents in Solr 6.6.2 version. The machine has 48 cores and 96 GB RAM. We are surprised that even on such large machine, Solr takes more than one second to find the result. There in'st any other load on Solr.

Following is the Query snippet with a sample query that took 8 seconds ( **& is replaced with new line here**)

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/select?bf=recip(ms(NOW,date),3.16e-11,1,1)%5E1.1
boost=product(title1_depth,product(sum(arank,div(div(sum(cal_score,cll_score),2),100),recip(pf_score,1,1,1)),sum(dup_stat,1)))
bq=group:top_web%5E1.37
defType=edismax
fq=group:web%20OR%20group:news*%20OR%20group:blog%20OR%20group:top_web*%20OR%20group:urpoetr*%20-pf_score:[0.7%20TO%201]%20OR%20NOT%20dup_stat1:[*%20TO%20*]
indent=on
mm=3
pf2=title%20content
pf3=title%20content
pf=title%20content
ps2=1
ps3=1
ps=10
q=اہم سماجی بہبود کی خدمات انجام دیتے ہیں تعلیم
qf=title%20content
tie=0.4
wt=json
stopwords=true
lowercaseOperators=true
start=0
rows=10
hl=true
hl.snippets=5
hl.fl=title+content_t+content+id+url+summary
hl.method=original
hl.fragsize=100
f.summary.hl.fragsize=0
f.title.hl.fragsize=0
hl.requireFieldMatch=false
hl.alternateField=title+content_t+content+id+url+summary
hl.simple.post=%3C/b%3E
hl.simple.pre=%3Cb%3E
fl=url
```

Where is the problem. We are expecting Solr should give response in less than 1 second. Most configurations are default and we have not changed anything in any file other than schema file.

Currently, I am testing it via a REST request on browser. In actual case, it is PHP.

Comment: It's hard to say _why_ it's taking time without starting to manipulate your query and looking at what field types you have, so start by removing the boost. It'll have to be calculated for each document being returned, so if many documents are hit, that may be the case. Turn off highlighting. Optimize your `fq` to be simpler to see if that affects anything. If you append `debug=timing` (or `all`) to your query, you'll also get debug information back about the time spent in each component.